# Can Intel Windows 10 be virtualized on Apple M1 host?

Tags: windows-10, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm considering getting an Apple M1 computer, but I'm wondering if I'll still be able to run Intel Windows 10 in, say, VM Ware Fusion.

If I get an M1 computer, will a virtualization application only be able to run "Windows on Arm" and unable to run "Intel Windows"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is impossible *by definition of the word "virtualization"*. If it were possible, it were *emulation*, not *virtualization*.

A *virtualizer* gives multiple guests the impression that they are the exclusive user of *something which exists*. So, if you have an AMD64 CPU, then you can run multiple guests and each thinks they are the only one running on that AMD64 CPU. If you have an ARM64 CPU, you can run multiple guests and each thinks they are the only one running on that ARM64 CPU.

An *emulator* provides *something which does not exist* by implementing ("emulating") it in software. So, if you don't have a GameBoy, you can use a GameBoy emulator to run GameBoy games. If you don't have a PowerPC CPU, you can use a PowerPC emulator to run PowerPC software. If you don't have an AMD64 CPU, you can use an AMD64 emulator to run AMD64 software.

Note #1: Sometimes, the lines get a little bit muddy, because most virtualizers also contain emulators for certain hardware: for example, full-system virtualizers like Parallels, VMWare, or VirtualBox typically contain emulators for network cards, graphics cards, hard disks, CD-ROMs, keyboards, pointing devices, etc. However, once you get clear about *which piece of hardware you are talking about*, that confusion should go away. E.g. VMWare *always* virtualizes the CPU, but typically emulates the network card. Those are just two different pieces of hardware, and you can virtualize one but emulate another.

Note #2: the ARM64 version of macOS actually *does* contain an AMD64 emulator called *Rosetta 2*. However, this is not a *full-system emulator*; it is only intended to allow AMD64 macOS and Darwin programs to run. It does not emulate the needed parts of the system to, e.g. boot an OS, it does not emulate a BIOS or UEFI, and so on.

So, what you need is an *emulator*, not a *virtualizer*.

And indeed, there are people who have had success with *emulators* even as early as Fall 2020, but it cannot be done with virtualizers.

One of the most popular emulators is [QEmu](https://qemu.org/), which does not only support emulating [AMD64](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/PC), but actually [many, many CPUs](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Do you have any experience with emulators? I wonder if they'd cause too much of a slowdown for something as big as Windows to be responsive with a reasonable workflow (browser, MS Word, etc.).

Comment: Depending on the particular host/guest combination, QEmu uses JIT compilation, and its JIT is pretty darn good. JIT *does* seem to be supported for ARM64 host / AMD64 guest.

Comment: This answer seems to ignore that there are Windows 10 builds on ARM, and the OP specifically asked about "Windows on ARM".  OTOH, the OP also said "run Intel Windows 10", which is contradictory.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is currently only the option to use an ARM based OS for Guest VMs. I tested it in Parallels Desktop mainly.

You can run x86 Apps emulated within the Windows 10 ARM-based Version as stated in the [official FAQ from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-arm-based-pcs-faq-477f51df-2e3b-f68f-31b0-06f5e4f8ebb5).

So to answer your question specifically, if you don't want to use an ARM-based image it isn't possible (yet).

Comment: I know, that x86 Apps can run, but the questions states, if a non ARM Version of Windows can be run with parallels. The german [Blog Post](https://www.parallels.com/de/blogs/parallels-desktop-m1/) from Parallels even states, that the Apps only run in the windows 10 ARM-based Version emulated by Windows. I edited my Answer for more clarity.

Comment: Oh, you're right and I was wrong. I think I need to go delete my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

VMware has an [excellent blog post](https://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2021/04/fusion-on-apple-silicon-progress-update.html) that details their thinking on progress.  In essence that are focusing on ARM based Linux as their first go round.  Rosetta 2 (Apple's machine interpreter which interprets x86 and executes ARM) is not built for virtualization so until that progresses the only option is Windows ARM.  That said, Windows ARM and virtualization cannot be installed on a Mac.

For right now there will not be any x86 emulated virtualized clients.